# How can I render 19451 circles on React Native map efficiently?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have 19451 points exported by coordinates in a JSON file. I am trying to render them in an efficient way on the map with circles. How can I achieve this? It is the first time I am using https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps with expo, so I am not that experienced in using maps services. I don't even know where to start from. I was thinking of something like rendering the points dynamically, based on whether one point is to be found in the region of the map that is currently shown on the screen, although I have no idea how to actually achieve this. The first thing I tried was to obviously render them at once: it takes ages and it is very buggy!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Use some kind of clustering when there are multiple circles in the same area, for example when you're zoomed out. Have a look at [react-native-maps-clustering](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-map-clustering). Performance wise is decent enough but it may lag on older devices.
2. When you go over a zoom level you can limit the number of circles you draw, I guess they overlap anyways. When your limit has been reached, you can display some warning to let the user know that the number of circles was limited and he should zoom in. From my experience, drawing max 50 custom markers was the upper limit to avoid lag on older devices. With circles, that limit might be different.
3. Manually filter your data and decide whether the circle belongs to the current viewport (visible part of the map) or not.

Some code would help me to give you some more hints.